# Images in sub folder not deploying

Tags: asp.net-core, web-publishing

I have a folder containing image files in wwwroot/images. Web Publish has stopped deploying them.

They're added to the project. They're in source control. But the build has stopped deploying them. Not happened before.

How do I make this software do what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The project file had accumulated some junk. For example, it had an odd selection of files as 'Content' and it was removing the images and adding them back not as content.

I deleted all of it. Mwahahaha.